# Disable twitter redirection page after sign in

Tags: php, twitter, hybridauth

[image]

The client asked to remove the twitter page when signing in for `twitter`

How do I disable `twitter` from redirecting to it's page(see above image) when signing in?

I'm using `HybridAuth`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is because of authorization, go to your twitter app settings and check the `Allow this application to use 'Sign in with Twitter'` option

```
ref: https://dev.twitter.com/blog/changes-to-sign-in-with-twitter
```

Comment: I didn't create the twitter app so I can't check it yet if it works but thanks, I'll accept once I confirmed it